# Django--HELP. django not creating sqlite database file as expected

Tags: python, django, sqlite

New to django

following tutorial 1. also looked up all related questions on stack overflow.  thought it was a absolute path issue...but absolute path seems to be correct. below is settings.py. any ideas?

```
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql',    'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'Users/Leerix/cars/carfilter/database/temp.db',                      #     Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used     with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
```

Below is the error i'm getting.  Been at this for several hours and cannot find the bug.  any help is greatly appreciated. Thx

```
python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420,  in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in   run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in   handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in  cursor
        cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
      File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 259, in _cursor
        self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)   
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant to use an absolute path (one starting with `/`) instead of a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the database file at that location. Also, the path starting with Users isn't absolute (is it?) make sure if you're on windows that it starts with a drive letter. (C:\)