# Django on Mac: can't create sqlite file

Tags: python, django

I'm newbie to Django, please bear with me. I follow this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) and get stuck for hours in creating a sqlite file by modifying `settings.py`. I know this question is [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256442/django-help-django-not-creating-sqlite-database-file-as-expected), but the answer doesn't work for me.

After I modify settings.py as following, I run `python manage.py syncdb` (and `sudo python manage.py syncdb`), but nothing happens in terminal. Also no db file is created in the path I specified.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/Users/philip/Documents/Developer/mysite/abc.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Comment: @iMom0 From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup): "If you're using SQLite, the database will be a file on your computer; in that case, NAME should be the full absolute path, including filename, of that file."

Comment: @AnujGupta but I can create db file using relative path.

Comment: @iMom0 Yes you can. What I meant was - Using an absolute path is probably not be the reason it's not working.

Comment: Philip, what do you mean when you say "nothing happens in terminal"? Do you get any output, or none at all? If you get any output, please add it to the question.

Comment: @AnujGupta, sorry for not being precise. I mean getting no output at all in terminal

Comment: @Philip007 Are you able to run `python manage.py shell`? If you are, can you try `from <appname> import models` for all your apps, and let us know if you get an error?

Comment: Thanks Anuj. I fix the problem by restart terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I restart terminal and it just works.